# Django template not loading or displaying

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I dont know why but i'm facing a strange problem.. My templates just wouldn't load or show. can you please help me out. I'm using Django version 1.7

It shows the following warning as well in the cmd :

> C:\Users\Om Computers\PyDisco\venv\ddisco\signups\forms.py:5: RemovedInDjango18Warning: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form SignUpForm needs updating
>     class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):

I have an application called ddisco and an app within it called signups and my templates are stored within the templates folder.

settings.py

```
   """
Django settings for ddisco project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'signups',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ddisco.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ddisco.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Template location
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticonly')
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^s/$', 'signups.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
     from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

# Create your models here.
class SignUp(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now = False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.email)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render , render_to_response, RequestContext

from .forms import SignUpForm
# Create your views here.
from django.template import Context, Template

def home(request):
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.save()

        return render_to_response(  "base.html",
                                            locals(),
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def home(request):  
        context = {}
        template = "base.html"
        return render(request, template, context)
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Homepage</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>


<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action 
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
-->
<div class="container">
      {% block sign%}
      {%endblock%}
<hr>

    <div class="container">


      <hr>

        <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
        </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

signup.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block sign %}
    <form class="form-horizontal col-lg-4" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token%}
    <legend>Sign Up</legend>
    <!--{{form.as_p}}-->
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: There at least three fairly obvious errors here: you have two URLs pointing to the same view name, 'home'; you actually have two view functions called 'home'; and you are not actually rendering the signup.html from either of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your home view twice. You need to remove this second view, so that is does not replace the first one:

```
def home(request):  
    context = {}
    template = "base.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Secondly, if you want to use your `signup.html`, you should include it when you render the template:

```
return render(request, "signup.html", locals())
```

I've used `render` because it's simpler, you can use `render_to_response` if you really want to.

The warning is just a warning, it is not an error. It is telling you to update your form class to include [`fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) before you upgrade to Django 1.8.

Comment: Note that there are also two URLs pointing to the home view. Perhaps OP meant to have one pointing to each of those view functions?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Good point. I'll wait for the op to respond before updating my answer.